# What does the package UPower output if on a desktop

Tags: linux, power-management

On Ubuntu 12.04, if I use the command:

```
    upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

It will output all of the statistics for the battery. However, what does it output if I am using a desktop (I.e. does not have a battery?)

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself

Comment: I don't have linux on a desktop.

Comment: Use `upower -e` to find out all devices, and then run `upower -i` specifying the path to the device. Specifying a path that probably doesn’t exist will just return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a workstation:

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Output:

```
failed to set path: cannot refresh: Cannot get device properties for
 /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0: Couldn't call GetAll() to 
 get properties for /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0: Method
 "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
 doesn't exist
```

#### Hardware details - cpu

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                3
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-2
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    3
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            16
Model:                 5
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              5787.62
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
```

#### Hardware details - motherboard

```
$ dmidecode -t baseboard
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASRock
    Product Name: M3A785GMH/128M
    Version:                       
    Serial Number:                       
    Asset Tag:                       
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:                       
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 0

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Type: SCSI Controller
    Status: Disabled
    Type Instance: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if a desktop does not have a battery to power itself, it may have other devices that provide power information. For instance, Apple iPads, Logitech Unifying HIDs and power meters do not provide any more to the system, but they can report power statistics.

Since the path provided to `upower -i` does not exist on a desktop (there is no battery, hence no `BAT0`), it obviously fails with an error.

Here is an example of `upower -d` on a desktop. It lists a Logitech K800 keyboard that has a rechargeable battery:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/keyboard_0003o046DoC52Bx000A
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0009/0003:046D:C52B.000A
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                K800
  serial:               FB841B86
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed 12 Feb 2014 12:11:10 PM CET (5 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  keyboard
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    percentage:          55%
  History (charge):
    1392203470  55.000   discharging

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.23
  can-suspend:     no
  can-hibernate:   no
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  no
  is-docked:       no
```